# Drag and drop content into textbox by using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to drag and drop content into Textbox and by my below code it drag upto textbox but not drop it there content.

```
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr[2]/th"));
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.name("search"));
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(from).moveToElement(to).release(to).build();
            dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try the following solution:

```
WebElement sourceelement  = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("XXX"));
Locatable element = (Locatable)sourceelement ;
Point p= element.getCoordinates().inViewPort();
int sourceX=p.getX();
int sourceY=p.getY();

WebElement destelement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("YYY"));
Locatable elementTarget = (Locatable)destelement;
Point Target= elementTarget.getCoordinates().inViewPort();
int targetX=Target.getX();
int targetY=Target.getY();
```

You may then use Robot to drag and drop the element