# Drag and Drop in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I try to drag and drop the content into search-textbox in selenium,but it perform drag operation but it not drop it into search-textbox.so my question is how to drop into textbox.

```
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159265/drag-and-drop-content-into-textbox-by-using-selenium");                 
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='qinfo']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/p/b"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.doubleClick(from).perform();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(from).moveToElement(to).release(to).build();
        dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Answer (score 2):

First WebDriver/Selenium DragAndDrop does not appear to work anymore, at best it goes between working and not working depending on release of drivers, browsers and selenium. I do not find that any of the java workarounds actually work.

```
clickAndHold() moveToElement() release()  // solutions don't work
```

I put together a working Java example after viewing the below mentioned sites. My solution is using rcorreia's javascript

[Elemental Selenium Drag N Drop](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop) - example app for testing Drag N Drop
[rcorreia/drag_and_drop_helper.js](https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544) - rcorreia's javascript helper code

[RomanIsko/elemental-selenium-tips](https://github.com/RomanIsko/elemental-selenium-tips/blob/master/39-drag-and-drop/csharp/DragAndDrop.cs) - a csharp implementation

I figured out how to integrate the javascript file by looking at romanisko csharp code.

```
JSDriver.ExecuteScript(dnd_javascript + "$('#column-a').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#column-b'});");
```

From the above I came up with the following Java Solution:

DragAndDropJsHelper.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class DragAndDropJsHelper {
    Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(DragAndDropJsHelper.class.getName());

    String dragndrop_js = null;

    public DragAndDropJsHelper(String jsFile) throws IOException {
        // the javascript file must be read into a single string no line breaks
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(getURIFromURL(jsFile)))) {
            dragndrop_js = br
                    .lines()
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // helper method, I'm using maven my js file is in src/test/resources
    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    private URI getURIFromURL(String fileName) {
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
            uri = url.toURI();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return uri;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Solution from elemental-selenium-tips
     * https://github.com/tourdedave/elemental-selenium-tips/blob/master/39-drag-and-drop/csharp/DragAndDrop.cs
     * JSDriver.ExecuteScript(dnd_javascript + "$('#column-a').simulateDragDrop({
     * dropTarget: '#column-b'});");
     * 
     * NOTE: Seems fragile, not sure if this works for XPATH or other src/dst type strings
     * TODO: would be good if it worked with WebElement, or BY
     * 
     * @param driver
     * @param src
     *            - css string for source element
     * @param dst
     *            - css string for destination element
     */
    public void dragDrop(WebDriver driver, String src, String dst) {
        String js = String.format("$('%s').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '%s'});",src,dst);
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript(dragndrop_js + js);
    }

}
```

Part of my DragAndDropTest.java

```
@Test
public void dragAtoBTest() {
    try {
        WebElement weA = driver.findElement(DragNDropPage.COLUMN_A);
        WebElement weB = driver.findElement(DragNDropPage.COLUMN_B);
        DragAndDropJsHelper ddh = new DragAndDropJsHelper("drag_and_drop_helper.js");

        ddh.dragDrop(driver, "#column-a", "#column-b");

        log.info("wait for opacity to change 1, indicating move complete");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(weA, "opacity", "1"));
        assertThat(weA.findElement(page.columnHeader).getText(), containsString("B"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(e);
        Assert.fail("FAILED validLoginTest");
    }
}
```

NOTE: Using the drag_and_drop.js requires the src and dst to be css selector strings, I don't know if xpath would work. It would be nicer if 
it would handle WebElement and/or BY for input parameters. Unfortunately, my javascript is not deep enough to make that modification.

see also:

[Selenium Actions drag and drop not working on chrome browser](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3269)

[Drag and drop support for an object via Gwen DSL](https://github.com/gwen-interpreter/gwen-web/issues/42)

Comment: @dhanush-jha I believe this is the correct answer you were looking for, please mark it as answered or let me know how I can correct it.

Answer (score 1):

So this thing made me crazy for a couple of days but I have found an answer.

Made a video about it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOprGzKBD9I&feature=youtu.be

To explain also in words/code what needs to be done

1 - You need to import an external JS file resources/drag_and_drop.js
2 - After you need to run make a function that will execute JS

Below is mine -

- This method implement the drag and drop action use selenium webdriver
- The strings need to be CSS Locations

  ```
    public void dragIT (String Fromlocator, String ToLocator) 



    String filePath = "resources/drag_and_drop.js";
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    String line;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
        buffer.append(line);

    String javaScript = buffer.toString();
    String commandToExecute =  "$('"+Fromlocator+"').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '"+ToLocator+"'});";

    javaScript = javaScript + commandToExecute;
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(javaScript)   }
  ```

Comment: Where is resources/drag_and_drop.js?

Comment: Here https://github.com/isolderea/Selenium-Recipes/tree/master/resources

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Actions dragAndDrop= new Actions(driver);
dragAndDrop.clickAndHold(DragFrom).moveToElement(DragTo).release().build().perform();
```

Comment: Should give more context for your answer.

Comment: Isn't it mentioned question itself?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this applies in some cases (when HTML5 draggable attribute is used).
Here is what I found: https://elementalselenium.com/tips/39-drag-and-drop

Here is my solution, I modified the javascript file a bit, so it will make use of `executeScript` optional `args` and not use string concatenation.

```
var source = arguments[0];
var target = arguments[1];
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.simulateDragDrop = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            new $.simulateDragDrop(this, options);
        });
    };
    $.simulateDragDrop = function(elem, options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.simulateEvent(elem, options);
    };
    $.extend($.simulateDragDrop.prototype, {
        simulateEvent: function(elem, options) {
            /*Simulating drag start*/
            var type = 'dragstart';
            var event = this.createEvent(type);
            this.dispatchEvent(elem, type, event);

            /*Simulating drop*/
            type = 'drop';
            var dropEvent = this.createEvent(type, {});
            dropEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
            this.dispatchEvent($(options.dropTarget)[0], type, dropEvent);

            /*Simulating drag end*/
            type = 'dragend';
            var dragEndEvent = this.createEvent(type, {});
            dragEndEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
            this.dispatchEvent(elem, type, dragEndEvent);
        },
        createEvent: function(type) {
            var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
            event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null);
            event.dataTransfer = {
                data: {
                },
                setData: function(type, val){
                        this.data[type] = val;
                },
                getData: function(type){
                        return this.data[type];
                }
            };
            return event;
        },
        dispatchEvent: function(elem, type, event) {
            if(elem.dispatchEvent) {
                elem.dispatchEvent(event);
            }else if( elem.fireEvent ) {
                elem.fireEvent("on"+type, event);
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
$(source).simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: target});
```

With this, you can simple call it with parameters now:

### Excerpt from **Java** test method:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
String script = Utils.readFileContents("/dragAndDrop.js");

// First Drag & Drop
js. executeScript(script, dndPage.getColumnA(), dndPage.getColumnB());
assertThat(dndPage.getColumnAHeaderText()).isEqualTo("B");
assertThat(dndPage.getColumnBHeaderText()).isEqualTo("A");
```

Hope this helps someone.